# JMock, Getting error

Tags: java, jmock

Getting error : java.lang.AssertionError: unexpected invocation: user.setUserName("John")
no expectations specified: did you...
 - forget to start an expectation with a cardinality clause?
 - call a mocked method to specify the parameter of an expectation?
what happened before this: nothing!
    at org.jmock.api.ExpectationError.unexpected(ExpectationError.java:23)

Code:

```
Mockery context = new JUnit4Mockery();

@Test
public void testSayHello(){
    context.setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
    final User user =  context.mock(User.class);
//  user.setUserName("John");
    context.checking(new Expectations(){{
        exactly(1).of(user);
        user.setUserName("John");
        will(returnValue("Hello! John"));
    }}
    );
     context.assertIsSatisfied();
    /*HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
    Assert.assertEquals(helloWorld.sayHelloToUser(user), "Hello! John");
    ;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting up expectations, you specify the method you'd like to mock by calling that method on the object returned by your call to `of()`, not on the mock itself (this isn't EasyMock).

```
@Test
public void testSayHello(){
    // setting up the mock
    context.setImposteriser(ClassImposteriser.INSTANCE);
    final User user =  context.mock(User.class);
    context.checking(new Expectations(){{
        exactly(1).of(user).setUserName("John");
        will(returnValue("Hello! John"));
    }});

    // using the mock
    HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
    String greeting = helloWorld.sayHelloToUser(user);

    // checking things afterward
    Assert.assertEquals(greeting, "Hello! John");
    context.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```